# How to tell java that a generic type is a functional interface?

Tags: java, generics, lambda

I have a generic functional interface to ask user about errors (pretty same as java.util.function.Function) and some parametrized subinterfaces:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Handler<Err,Resp> {
    public Resp handle(Err param);
}
@FunctionalInterface
public interface RecoverableErrorHandler<Err> extends Handler<Err, RecoverableErrorResult > {}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface RetryIgnoreErrorHandler<Err> extends Handler<Err, RetryIgnoreAbortResult> {}
```

I want to add logging to each handler by wrapping handler into another handler:

```js
private <Err,Resp,H1 extends Handler<Err,Resp> > H1 addLogToHandler(String s, H1 h) {
    return (Err arg) -> {
        Resp res = h.handle(arg);
        logger.info(s+" returned "+res);
        return res;
    };
}

// some code omitted
RecoverableErrorHandler<String> netErrorHandler = ... // shows dialog and asks user what to do
netErrorHandler = addLogToHandler("Network Error handler", netErrorHandler);
```

This does not compile with `error: incompatible types: H1 is not a functional interface` on line with `return`.

The question is, can I tell java that generic `H1` is a functional interface? Or, how do I make this code work?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Your return type is the generic parameter `H1`. How can you create an instance of `H1` without knowing its actual type?

Comment: Does not java infer types in the place where function is called by its arguments and required return types? In my example, I could tell that in ``netErrorHandler = addLogToHandler("Network Error handler", netErrorHandler);`` type of H1 should be `RecoverableErrorHandler<String>`

Comment: That's the call site, not within the method. You're essentially trying to do `public <T extends Animal> T method() {return new Dog();}`. How is that ever going to work? What if I want to invoke this method and use `Cat` as the generic type argument?

Comment: Well, that's when the type it matches the lambda to is a concrete type which can be checked. The fact that you have a class which extends an interface doesn't mean that it doesn't happen to extend other interfaces. And which of those is going to be the functional interface to match?

Comment: Ok then, any ideas on how to achieve described functionality?

Comment: You're essentially trying to add a logging proxy. Stick to the base interface. Declare `netErrorHandler` as a `Handler` instead and get rid of the bounded `H1` type parameter. The method parameter can just be of type `Handler`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did for now, dropped subinterfaces and used base Handler. Hoped to find another solution. Thank you.

Comment: You can still have your interfaces, but return type of your method will have to be just handler `Handler`, or one of the more concrete types. Or you could overload the method and copy-paste the code if handler interface `RetryIgnoreErrorHandler` will mean something to rest of your system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to tell the compiler that `H1` is supposed to be a functional interface, in fact, you can’t even tell it that `H1` is supposed to be an interface.

When you think about it, you may notice that even if you were able to restrict `H1` to be a functional interface extending `Handler<Err,Resp>`, there was no guaranty that this type has a functional type compatible to the lambda expression in your code.

E.g., the following would be a type fulfilling the constraints:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Foo<E,R> extends Handler<E,R>, Runnable {
    default R handle(E param) { run(); return null; }
}
```

this is a functional interface and it extends `Handler`, but the attempt to implement it within `addLogToHandler` with a `(Err) -> Resp` signature can’t work.

The solution is simple. Just drop the sub interfaces `RecoverableErrorHandler<Err>` and `RetryIgnoreErrorHandler<Err>` completely. They offer no advantage over using `Handler<Err,RecoverableErrorResult>` resp. `Handler<Err,RetryIgnoreAbortResult>` directly.

After eliminating the subtypes, you can change the method to

```
private <Err,Resp> Handler<Err,Resp> addLogToHandler(String s, Handler<Err,Resp> h) {
    return arg -> {
        Resp res = h.handle(arg);
        logger.info(s+" returned "+res);
        return res;
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I did in the end.